# Can we get rid of style identification questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, style-identification

Can we just get rid of style identification questions?

Nearly all of them are post some image with no title or text asking for a style that may or may not even be something classifiable. There's simply too many permutations and styles for us to identify and the vast majority of these questions are incredibly low quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are now some [style-identification guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2929/23061) that have been made to improve the quality of these types of questions. It would be nice if we would close ones *not* following these guidelines but leave open others, as I believe they are valid for the reasons that John mentions.

## Update:

The close reason for font identification and critiques now includes the above Style Identification.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Zach. Just updated the close reason

Answer (score 5):

I'm always hesitant to prune scope just because it attracts low quality questions. This tag isn't *all* bad.

- [What is the style of font called that is typically used in newspaper mastheads?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/9155/8708)
- [Is there a name for logos with four letters in the quadrants of an X?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41961/8708)
- [How do you call tall, thick fonts, similar to Bebas?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/19441/8708)

I do agree this is a problem, but I don't agree with just outright nuking. This problem you're identifying is far from exclusive to [style-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-identification) questions. We've all seen it over and over again with Photoshop or Illustration questions, e.g. "How can I create this effect?" with maybe a couple images of what they're trying to do and what they've already done.

Instead, I would propose generic guidelines on how to write a quality post that can effectively be searched for. We don't need a close reason for this, this is what downvoting is for. A downvote and a constructive comment would work just fine.

> "*Hello, I've downvoted your post because it could use some serious improvement. Please consult [these tips](/#) for guidance on how it could be improved. Specifically, your title is very generic; you should aim for it to be unique to the problem you're trying to solve.*"

Comment: nuking is more fun :'( and the majority of people asking these questions either a. don't return, b. dont know english well enough to read the guidelines, c. don't care, or d. all of the above

Comment: @Ryan but that's no reason to penalise those who do do it right, or those of us who might want a style identified one day. [Here's one I asked a while ago where some guy called Ryan gave it a good answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17069/name-for-blocky-imprecise-illustration-style-like-saul-bass-paul-rand)... :-)

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better in my opinion to just get rid of the tag, close all questions of the type. If someone attempts to make something in the style THEY Identified then they can ask about their attempt and what might be off.

For example:

#### Bad Question

- [What is the style of illustration on this sculpture called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58880/what-is-this-style-of-art-called)
- [What style is this image?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62543/what-style-is-this-image)
- [What is this design style called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58531/what-is-this-design-style-called)

Guess what's in each one? Oh, you can't! Its an image, with little to no text, so we can't sort it, hard to remember for when the style turns up again, and little use to anyone.

The person needs to describe what the image is, in detail, and if they can do that then they can put it into a search engine themselves to find. In my opinion these questions (and Font Identification questions) should be closed.

If the person attempts to create one of the images in the said style and its not coming out then they can ask for help nailing the style. That's an interesting question.

This is getting old though between people posting ticker tape fonts for the umpteenth time asking us to identify some minute variation, or someone posting the an image of some generic illustration / graphic and asking us to classify it.

Let 'em burn, let 'em all burn

Comment: IMO we should close questions like the ones you link as unclear (because we don't know exactly what in the image they are referencing) and comment with some requirements for this type of question