# Can we set some guidelines for "Style Identification" questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, asking-questions, style-identification

> **UPDATE: The actual guidelines without any discussion - [What are the requirements for style identification questions?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2930/52050)**

It's evident from this recent discussion - [Can we get rid of style identification questions?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2896/can-we-get-rid-of-style-identification-questions) and recent chat that the number of low quality style identification questions is becoming a problem. These posts are often not much more than an image or images and "what style is this?".

Examples of recent questions:

- [How to call a genre of art with perfectionistic figures?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68185/how-called-genre-of-art-with-perfectionistic-figures)
- https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67587/style-identification-please-what-is-the-keyword-for-this-painting-style
- [What is the style of illustration on this sculpture called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58880/what-is-this-style-of-art-called)
- [What style is this image?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62543/what-style-is-this-image)
- [What is this design style called?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58531/what-is-this-design-style-called)

I do think we can encourage good style id questions with some guidelines similar to the [Requirements for font identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366/52050) & [Guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682/52050).

Almost all of the font identification requirements translate to style identification perfectly (maybe with the exception of font id services) and we can use those requirements as a starting point. So... **Can we come up with some general guidelines for asking style identification questions?**

Comment: Not sure how relevant it is here, but analysis questions about the "meaning"/"use" of a design/illustration could benefit from a readily available framework such as the Six Thinking Hats. By looking at artwork and design from a list of fixed mindsets such as "Semiotic/Emotional perspective", "Functional/Designer mindset" (if available), or "Historical/Contextual mindset",etc, it sets out a list of different perspectives from which a piece of work can be deconstructed. It would also make all style questions relatable. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Thinking_Hats

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to promote high quality style identification questions, we ask that you follow a specific format. If your question has been placed on hold, please edit it to meet the following criteria:

#### ✔ DO: Use a descriptive title

So that we don't have hundreds of questions titled "What style is this?", we ask that you be as descriptive as possible in your title. Here are some examples on how it should be worded:

- What style of font is used for ACME Inc.'s logo?
- What style is the illustration on this event poster?
- What style of design does example.com use for their navigation menu?

This helps keep the question useful to others and improves searchability.

#### ✔ DO: Add an image or images of

We're not psychic, we need to see what you are talking about! You can use the built in image uploader to include images of the style you are interested in. Uploading more than one image may be a good idea, but don't go overboard. As long as the style you are interested in is distinct enough then you shouldn't need more than a few images - if you do, what you are looking at probably isn't distinct enough to be a considered a style.

#### ✔ DO: Tell us where it is from

Sometimes the origin of the images you post can help provide clues to identify it. As much relevant information as possible will go a long way. Include a link if it's from a digital source, such as a website or PDF.

#### ✔ DO: Detail what you've attempted already to try and identify the style you are interested in

A simple search on your favoured search engine will often get you what you want. You can also use reverse image searches to find the source of your image.

If none of those give you successful results, let us know which ones you have tried so that we're not re-tracing steps you may have already taken.

#### ✘ DO NOT: Ask about multiple styles in one question

Stack Exchange aims to answer objectively answerable questions. If you're asking about more than one style in one question, it opens up the potential for multiple correct answers. Keep it to one style per question so that your post fits the Stack Exchange format.

#### Other ways to improve your post

Make sure what you are asking about *is* a distinct style. Just because something uses the same shapes or colors does not mean they are the same style. Similarly, every small design decision does not have to correspond to a distinct *style*.

You should also avoid hot-linking to images on external sites. We cannot dependably rely on the longevity of external hosts, so please use the built in image uploader.

You can help with our site's organization by properly tagging it. Start off by tagging it as [style-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-identification) and narrow it down by using  applicable descriptors such as [illustration](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustration), [typography](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography), [line-art](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-art). Please do not include superfluous tags such as "style".

### Examples of well formed style identification questions

- [What is the style of font called that is typically used in newspaper mastheads?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/9155/8708)
- [Is there a name for logos with four letters in the quadrants of an X?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41961/8708)
- [How do you call tall, thick fonts, similar to Bebas?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/19441/8708)

---

The current close reason could also be updated to include style identification without any rewording.

> Your question appears to be incomplete. More detail is needed for relevant and focused answers to be provided for these types of questions. Please review our [**font identification**](http://goo.gl/MecB9X), [**style identification**](http://goo.gl/YGhWYK) or [**critique**](http://goo.gl/9NRvxg) requirements and provide the missing details, so that your question can be answered.