# If you want change, lead the community to change

Tags: discussion

I would like to point out that change in the GD.SE happens because of the way you operate. If you wish there to be guideline for X, Y be allowed and Z be acceptable, then you have to work on it. Complaining or asking others to do so is only so effective. Leading others is very effective.

So for example one thing lot of people complain about is that 3d questions are not being answered. Well, they are not currently being actively closed either*. So what is needed is somebody who consistently answers these questions in a thoughtful and knowledgeable way. Because the community does not cater to these questions they are also implied to be out of topic. By answering these questions it becomes possible to include them into our mainstream.

The same logic applies to a lot of things if questions seem to often be of low quality. Edit them or make a resource that helps users to write better questions. So for example, if you want a guideline for [style identification questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/can-we-set-some-guidelines-for-style-identification-questions), then go ahead and suggest what would be in that guideline.

Everything here works on voluntary basis you cannot force others to do things for you. You can compel them to, so yes opening discussion is first step. But after that first step there needs to be a commitment from somebody. If only you.

So the question is can you do it? We need leaders, and we need more of them. Take charge.

* which in my mind is a better solution

Comment: This community is moderated by YOU. Great post, joojaa.

Comment: We talked about this in meta before, maybe a year ago. You know why I don't go through the edit queue? there are routinely more than 50 posts to review A DAY. Right now the queue is at 65. I can't keep up with that.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Same problem... But threes more to leadership than review moderation.

Comment: Recognition and appreciation of those that do actively edit would motivate users more. I don't remember getting a "thanks for your effort" or "good job" for all the work I put in. It may have happened once or twice, but I can't remember and it wasn't consistent. I'm not asking for one now obviously, simply pointing out what may have motivated me to continue, and hoping it can be applied to our great new users that have taken up the mantle.

Comment: @Dom no, but you do get complaints and nagging. Problem is that thats the best you can hope from strangers on internet

Comment: Well @joojaa, as you say, lead the community to change. I'm not on that often anymore so I won't notice much but there are plenty of people who could go around saying thanks, it costs nothing and means everything.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Nobody asks you to trawl through all the reviews. I don't (gasp!) do that myself, the numbers are just too staggering, I totally agree. Just do a few, and that's help enough :)

Comment: @dom same rule applies for the mods.  I dont recall the last time someone told the mods hey thanks for taking the time to deal with a lot.  We dont get paid but we do it because we love design.  However im not going to stop just because it isn't there..  just pointing that out there for you too..  ;)

Comment: @Darth I voted for you to become a mod as thanks for your effort.. It could be said more, but as I said I'm not around so I don't see much. I'm pretty sure the term "our excellent mods" or similar has popped up in a few meta posts as well..

Comment: @LaurenIpsum It's also not that many new posts a day. That number is an accumulation of a while - I only see a few new ones in my queue a day

Comment: @ZachSaucier I was doing many, but, referencing the same meta discussion, 85% of them were "my Adobe be broke" (™ Scott) and I was just funnelling stuff to SuperUser. Ultimately we are all here as volunteers, and it just... wasn't... fun anymore.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I understand and was with you. Recently the queue hasn't been so bad (thankfully!)